# Sort Date column which is in MM/dd/yyyy format in sqlite

Tags: android, sqlite, date, database-design, datetimepicker

I want to get the max date first but the following query does not return the correct data

```
Cursor mCursor = db.rawQuery("select * from "
                + ESERVICE_TICKET_SYNC_TABLE + " where " + ESERVICE_SEND_STATUS
                + " = ? AND " + ESERVICE_USER_ID + " = ? order by date("
                + ESERVICE_CREATION_DATE + ") DESC ", new String[] {
                send_status, user_id });
```

I had stored the ESERVICE_CREATION_DATE in the format mm/dd/yyyy which is a text.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do `" = ? AND " + ESERVICE_USER_ID + " = ? ORDER BY "+ ESERVICE_CREATION_DATE + "DESC "`

Answer (score 0):

Correct usage of "order by is": `order by COLUMN_NAME desc`

Comment: What happened? Was there any error log? Did you check the question that marked as dublicate? What did you try to solve?

Comment: No thier are no error logs but i have solved the problem by creating one more column and store the time value of the date in it using date.getTime(); and then use the order by time desc querry in it.

Comment: lol actually i think you cant save the date as a Date in SQLite, i checked my code, in also saving it as a long derived from .getTime() method!